# Is there an API for asking the Google Assistant general questions via plaintext?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I'm looking for a way to integrate the Google Assistant into my chatbot and be able to get answers to general questions like "whats the weather?", "how tall is X?", "what does X mean?" etc. (just how Google Home works). Ideally this would be over a REST API and I'd get the response back inside of a JSON payload.

I looked through the Google Assistant SDK docs but it wasn't clear on how I could host/build an API that does this. Any ideas on if something like this already exists?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you use the [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk).

There isn't a REST API, since other requirements for the SDK are poorly suited for REST. Instead it uses [gRPC](https://www.grpc.io/), which lets them publish a standard interface and lets you [compile this interface](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/integrate#other-languages) to local language bindings.

IF you are using Python, C++, or Node.js, there are already [libraries](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/integrate#python) available which allow you to skip the gRPC setup yourself.